# Problem including xmmintrin.h in my c++ builder application

Tags: c++, c++builder, sse, intrinsics

I'm trying to write some SIMD code (in C++Builder 10.1 Berlin), but I'm getting an `E2257` error in `mmintrin.h` (which is included by `xmmintrin.h`, which should be included for SIMD stuff). There's a bunch of identical errors, so it seems that bcc32 can't handle the syntax found in those headers.

For instance, all the lines containing `__atribute__` seems to cause this error:

```
typedef long long __m64 __attribute__((__vector_size__(8)));
```

To me, this does seem like a C++builder bug, but I'm not sure, and to be honest I'm not familiar with `__atribute__` (this doesn't seem to be a C++ keyword, so I assume it's either a function/macro or a language extension).

UPDATE: Since C++  Builder 10.1 Berlin can use Clang (`bcc32c` as opposed to the old compiler `bcc32`) , I tried that as well and that helped remove all the `E2257` errors. Unfortunately, I'm now getting  an ICE ( [bcc32c Error] FillObj.cpp(1): ICE: Internal compiler error: C0000005 @ 27287E3D ). The culprit is this line `_mm_storeu_ps(&a[i], xmm0 );` Commenting out this line makes the code compile. This code is just an example but it's enough to recreate the problem.

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

void SumValues(float * a, float * b, unsigned len){

    __m128 xmm0, xmm1;
    //for this simple example , it's assumed len is divisible by     
    for(int i=0; i<len; i += 4){

      xmm0 = _mm_loadu_ps( &a[i] );
      xmm1 = _mm_loadu_ps( &b[i] );

      xmm0 = _mm_add_ps(xmm0, xmm1);

      _mm_storeu_ps( &a[i], xmm0 );//this line is causing the ICE described above

    }
}
```

As I said in a comment , this works fine in Qt (using MinGw 5.5.0 ). About the Clang compiler, I'm not exactly sure which version it is, but since it has to support all the VCL stuff, I don't think it's a standard clang compiler.

Comment: That syntax is a GNU C extension (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html).  Each compiler usually has its own version of headers like that, e.g. MSVC's would look nothing like that (instead using a union of structs).  Are you manually using GCC's `xmmintrin.h` with bcc32?  Are you sure bcc32 even supports SSE code-gen at all?  https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/general-development/f/tools-22/34615/mmx-sse-for-bcc32c-in-ide does say there's a `-mmmx` command-line option which might also enable SSE.

Comment: Where in the C++ Builder (Berlin version) documentation are you reading about `__attribute__`?

Comment: @Peter Cordes,I'm not sure that bcc32 supports SSE but these two headers come bundled with C++ builder so that was my assumption (this is not specific to C++ builder berlin, these headers have been a part of the c++ builder installation for as long as I remember).

Comment: @Eljay, see my comment to Peter.

Comment: Ok, if it came with that header, then you might just need a build option like `-mmmx` to enable it.  GCC will also error if you try to use SSE intrinsics in 32-bit code without enabling SSE.  You didn't quote the exact error message so IDK.  (Or is there just that number with no text?  If so, then you should go look up that error code in the docs and copy/paste or link it in your question.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes , yeah it's just that number with nothing else. In Qt (with either MinGw or gcc) I usually just put `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE +=  -msse` in  .pro file and that's enough. C++Builder Berlin can optionally use Clang so perhaps I'll try that as well.

Comment: clang/LLVM will have no problem with GNU C extensions, including using the same syntax for vector extensions.  If you can use a good modern compiler like clang, do it!  Preferably with `-march=pentium-m -mtune=haswell` or something similar, if you want to assume SSE3 and other pretty old extensions as a baseline.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, thank you for your help. I'll try clang and report back.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, compiling this with clang does remove the above error but now I'm getting an ICE ( [bcc32c Error] FillObj.cpp(1): ICE: Internal compiler error: C0000005 @ 25907E3D ) . The problem is this line    _mm_storeu_ps( &a[i], x );. If I remove this line, then everything compiles just fine. This does seem to be a bug because that code works in Qt (with MinGw)

Comment: Ok, so maybe that header only comes with C++Builder for use with clang, the old compiler?  But what version of clang is it using?  I don't have C++Builder and you're not giving enough info to make sense of what's going on, or an [mcve] of the source that causes a problem.  You could try it with a mainstream compiler on https://godbolt.org/.  (Although really, an ICE is *always* a compiler bug; a situation the compiler can't handle should be reported via an error message, not a crash.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes, I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the 10.4 Sydney 64-bit Windows C++ compiler in the IDE and your example compiles and executes for me.

```
void SumValues(float * a, float * b, unsigned len){
    __m128 xmm0, xmm1;
    //for this simple example , it's assumed len is divisible by
    for(int i=0; i<len; i += 4){

      xmm0 = _mm_loadu_ps( &a[i] );
      xmm1 = _mm_loadu_ps( &b[i] );
      xmm0 = _mm_add_ps(xmm0, xmm1);
      _mm_storeu_ps( &a[i], xmm0 );//this line is causing the ICE described above
    }
}

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    //
    float myA[4],myB[4];
    myA[0] = 0.0;
    myA[1] = 1.0;
    myA[2] = 2.0;
    myA[3] = 3.0;
    myB[0] = 0.0;
    myB[1] = 1.0;
    myB[2] = 2.0;
    myB[3] = 3.0;
    SumValues(myA,myB,4);
    Button1->Caption = FloatToStr(myA[2]);
}
```

Comment: it seems then  that the problem is resolved in C++ 10.4 Sydney.

Comment: I found the following IFDEFs in the 10.4 source code:

#if defined(__clang__)

  #if (__clang_major__ == 5 && __clang_minor__ == 0)

    #include <clang5.0\xmmintrin.h>

  #elif (__clang_major__ == 3 && __clang_minor__ == 3)

    #include <clang3.3\xmmintrin.h>

  #else

    #error "Unable to determine correct clang header version"

  #endif

#else

    #error "Only supported for clang compilers"

#endif

Comment: those ifdefs are not present in 10.1 Berlin (at least I didn't see them) so I can  assume they were    added in more recent versions of the compiler.

Comment: I was also told by an Embarcadero employee (just yesterday via email)  that SSE stuff is supported only by 64-bit Clang compilers. The 32 bit compilers still pass values via FPU (he didn't specify reasons for this). This might explain why you managed to get my example working.

Comment: in 10.4 Sydney the ifdef for clang with xmmintrin.h can be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\include\windows\crtl\xmmintrin.h